# Save data between calls to the server in Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, struts2

I have an `Action` class as below:

```
public XyzAction extends ActionSupport{

public String method1(){
  // Get the Map by calling a stateless Session bean
  Map m = remoteInterface.getMap();   
}


public String method2(){

}
}
```

Now an `Action` is called which maps to `method1` and my Map get filled and I use the `Map` values to fill my **drop-down** in my JSP.

Now in the JSP user clicks a submit button and an `Action` is called which maps to `method2` where some data is retrieved from DB and the same JSP has to display the data in a `div` and I also need to show the previous *drop-down*.

So how do I save the Map so that I can display even after the second call to the server?
Should I store it in a session and retrieve in my JSP like:

```
<s:select name="#session.map" />
```

or do we have other options?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a bean to the complete session by using the scope
"session".

So just declare a bean using this scope and struts generates one instance of this
bean for the whole session. You can use this bean amongst multiple requests.

This bean would be a good place to store variables which are needed during the whole web session.

Comment: Ok..I didn't know about this. Can u help with some code to get me started or link?

Comment: Take a look here: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from session via OGNL expression `"#session.map"` you need to change the code, so

```
public String method1(){
  // Get the Map by calling a stateless Session bean
  Map m = remoteInterface.getMap(); 
  Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession(); 
  session.put("map", m);
  return SUCCESS; 
}
```

In the `method2` you have to check if the value is available

```
public String method2(){
  Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
  if (session.get("map") == null){
    addActionError("map is null");
    return ERROR;
  }  
  return SUCCESS; 
}
```

If you see the code that gets the session map from the action context is repeating, so why it's better to inject the session map to the action property. It is another, better way to get the session map to your action by implementing `SessionAware` interface.

Comment: I know about SessionAware and how to put a variable into session. What basically I wanted to ask was that keeping the variable in a  session scope is the only option available here if we want it on the second server call? As I feel only things like userId be kept in a session. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can keep things like userId in parameters between requests (that what the hidden fields for), but if you want to keep a collection and want to save on keeping it in the session then you have an option to utilize a session map, or interceptor, or container, or servlet. You can also save in the cookie.

Comment: So to retain a variable on the second server call, only option I have is to keep it in a session scope (via session map, or interceptor, or container, or servlet) ???

Comment: This is in reference to 1st part of my question in this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944860/maintaining-values-of-action-variables?noredirect=1#comment31456174_20944860

Comment: I didn't get you do you want to retain the map values on the first action call or do you want to reload it in the second action? Also, forgot to tell you the references to the map values you can keep in the action, the data in the session.

Comment: After I get map value in 1st method the page loads filling dropdown with those values. Then when submit button presses and method2 get called and it redirect back to same page, so after 2nd method return map values are lost

Comment: @Roaman C: references to the map values you can keep in the action, the data in the session?? Din get you

Comment: It can't be lost because it in the session, you can reload a page to make sure the values are there. Instead of `#session.map` you can use simple `map` field from the action, like in your second question but when the action called you should initialize it with the reference from session.

Comment: OK. the second part of the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944860/maintaining-values-of-action-variables ? Do you have any idea?