# Maintaining values of action variables?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, url-parameters

```
class SampleAction extends ActionSupport {
private Map<String,String> circleIdNameMap;

public String preprocess(){
--logic for populating value of MAP
}
--getters and setters
}
```

Now my problem is on page load I call `preprocess` function and populate the value of `Map`. After page submit another method is called and during that after some DB interaction it redirects to JSP, but this time the value of `Map` is empty. I am using this `Map` for drop-down tag in Struts2.

My `preprocess` is associated in the link like:

```
href="/gma/preprocessConfigureTspThreshold?operatorId=5102&sessionId=12332"‌`​
```

So only first time when the link is clicked `preprocess` is called, after that when I redirect to my JSP so its not called then, so second time the value of `Map` is empty.

1. Shall I put the map in a session so that it is retained? Or can do something else?
2. I read that don't use `preprocess` function, use `Preparable` interface. But as per docs:

   > The prepare method will always be called by the Struts 2 framework's prepare interceptor
   >   whenever any method is called for the Action class.

So, it will be called for every method. I want `preprocess` to be called only when page loads.

Comment: How are you calling method `on page load`? If it is get called on page load then how map is empty? You can simply call `preprocess()` just before `return ERROR;` then on JSP map will not be empty.

Comment: prepare method will get called when there is a request to you action..so be it page load or anything use case

Comment: @Aniket: My preprocess is associated in the link like: 
     href="/gma/preprocessConfigureTspThreshold?operatorId=5102&sessionId=12332"! So only first time when the link is clicked preprocess is called, after that when i redirect to my JSP so it;s not called

Comment: "After page submit" means there's another request. Actions are instantiated per-request; any data in a previous action will obviously not be there in subsequent requests unless it's filled somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The `prepare` method of the [`Preparable`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Preparable.html) action class is called on every action execution, that's right. That might be the reason why you prepare the map for a drop-down in the `preprocess` method.

```
public class SampleAction extends ActionSupport {
    private Map<String,String> circleIdNameMap;
    private String circleId;
    //getters and setters here

    protected boolean reload = false;

    private void preprocess(){
      // Get the Map by calling a stateless Session bean
      circleIdNameMap = remoteInterface.getMap(); 
    }

    public String action1(){
      preprocess();
      Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession(); 
      session.put("circleIdNameMap ", circleIdNameMap );
      return SUCCESS; 
    }

    public String action2(){
      Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
      circleIdNameMap = (Map<String,String>)session.get("circleIdNameMap"); 
      if (circleIdNameMap == null){
        if (reload) {
          preprocess();
          Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession(); 
          session.put("circleIdNameMap ", circleIdNameMap );
        } else {
          addActionError("circleIdNameMap is null");
          return ERROR;
        }
      }  
      return SUCCESS; 
    }

   ...//other actions
}
```

the JSP for drop-down

```
<s:select name="circleId" list="circleIdNameMap" listKey="key" listValue="value"/>
```

The meaning of this code is: you should not return result `SUCCESS` or `INPUT` if fields in JSP aren't initialized.